# Want to customise or change the message that get displayed in Password prompt in password protected PDF

Tags: pdf

Is there a way to customise or change the message that gets displayed in the document open Password dialog box while trying to open a password protected PDF file.

**Default message - "filename.pdf  is protected. please enter a Document Open Password."**

Answer (score 4):

The message shown is completely up to the PDF viewer or processor in question.

In general you cannot prescribe it but you may create your own viewer showing the text you prefer.

**PS:** As the OP still hoped for a different answer (and asked essentially a duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26040471/1729265)):

The [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) in regard to opening password protected PDF files only rules:

> If a user attempts to open an encrypted document that has a user password, the conforming reader shall first try to authenticate the encrypted document using the padding string defined in 7.6.3.3, "Encryption Key Algorithm" (default user password):
>
> - If this authentication attempt is successful, the conforming reader may open, decrypt and display the document on the screen.
> - If this authentication attempt fails, the application should prompt for a password. Correctly supplying either password (*owner* or *user* password) should enable the user to open the document, decrypt it, and display it on the screen.
>
> *([ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) section 7.6.3.1)*

It does **not** present any mechanism to supply a message for prompting for the password.

Please note that the specification even makes *prompting for a password* merely a **recommendation** ("should", not "shall"). Completely in accord with the specification, therefore, other ways to retrieve a password might be tried instead, or such password protected documents might be ignored completely!

That been said specific PDF viewers *might allow* to provide a prompting message in a proprietary manner; after all the early signing mechanisms in Adobe Reader even allowed the PDF to *provide appearances for successfully and for unsuccessfully verified signatures* which made frauds possible! I doubt, though, that current versions of serious viewers allow providing password prompt messages even in a proprietary way.

Comment: Thanks Mkl.

I created my own password protected PDF and i want to customize that message for my application.
is there a way to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: There isn't, at least no general one.